# Taylor formula for a function of multivariate variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

We know that if we have a function with several variables $x_1,\dots, x_n$, the second degree Taylor expansion around $a=(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ gives

$f(x_1, ... , x_n) \approx f(a)+Df(a)(x-a)+\frac{1}{2}(x-a)^THf(a)(x-a), $

where $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, $Df(x)$ represents the $1\times n$ gradient matrix and $Hf(x)$ represents the $n\times n$ hessian matrix.

Here, each variable is real-valued, i.e.,  $x_i \in \mathbb{R}, i=1,\dots,n.$

But suppose now that each variable is a vector variable, i.e., $\boldsymbol{x}_i \in \mathbb{R}^p, i=1,\dots,n.$ Does the Taylor formula be the same for $f(\boldsymbol{x}_1, ... , \boldsymbol{x}_n)$ around $a=(\boldsymbol{a}_1,\dots,\boldsymbol{a}_n)$?

Comment: I think you can identify your function with a function that depends only on scalars. For example, it's common in physics to have a function $f$ of the position and time: $f(\vec{r},t)$, but we can identify it with a function $f(x,y,z,t)$, because $\vec{r}$ is a function of $x,y,z,t$: $\vec{r}(x,y,z,t)$. So we have that $f(\vec{r},t)=f(\vec{r}(x,y,z,t),t)=f(x,y,z,t)$

Comment: Ok. It's just I must be able to compute the differences $x-a$, which are differences of 2 vectors.

Comment: Basically, if you have $f(x_1,...,x_i)$ with $x_j \in \mathbb{R}^{k_j}$, you can treat it as $f((x_{1})_1,...,(x_1)_{k_1},...,(x_i)_{k_i})$.

Comment: I see! That's a way of seeing the variables!